# When I click send The app stops working

Tags: android-studio, android-asynctask, fatal-error

The code for   button is

```
   b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            s = DateEdit.getText().toString();

            new AsyncTaskPayment().execute(s);
        }
    });
```

The async class is

```
  private class AsyncTaskPayment extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private final String TAG = null;

    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Wait..");
        Dialog.show();
        Log.e(TAG, "------------------------------------- Here");
    }


    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

            // Field

            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
            jObject.put("classname", s);
            jObject.put("time", s);
            jObject.put("faculty", s);
            jObject.put("message", s);
            MultipartEntityBuilder se = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

            se.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            se.addPart("request", new StringBody(jObject.toString()));
            httppost.setEntity((org.apache.http.HttpEntity) se);

            HttpResponse resp = Client.execute(httppost);

            Content = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

            Log.e("Response", "--------------------------------" + Content);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is Debug error i get

> 01-14 07:33:08.359    2246-2268/com.push.ra1.cancel E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>       Process: com.push.ra1.cancel, PID: 2246
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/http/Consts;
>               at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody.(StringBody.java:147)
>               at com.push.ra1.cancel.MainActivity$AsyncTaskPayment.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:154)
>               at com.push.ra1.cancel.MainActivity$AsyncTaskPayment.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:120)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.http.Consts" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.push.ra1.cancel-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>               at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>               at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody.(StringBody.java:147)
>               at com.push.ra1.cancel.MainActivity$AsyncTaskPayment.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:154)
>               at com.push.ra1.cancel.MainActivity$AsyncTaskPayment.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:120)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
>               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>       Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.Consts
>               at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>               at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>               at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>               ... 10 more
>        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
>   01-14 07:33:10.669    2246-2246/com.push.ra1.cancel I/Choreographer? Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   01-14 07:33:17.331    2246-2246/com.push.ra1.cancel I/Choreographer? Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>   01-14 07:33:23.327    2246-2246/com.push.ra1.cancel E/WindowManager? android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.push.ra1.cancel.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1586a180 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,232} that was originally added here
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
>               at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
>               at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
>               at com.push.ra1.cancel.MainActivity$AsyncTaskPayment.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:132)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
>               at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
>               at com.push.ra1.cancel.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:63)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)